# Converting an UNIX python program to work in windows

Tags: python, windows, unix

I need to make a program that drives a DYMO LabelManager PnP label printing device. DYMO provides a SDK for this purpose, but after some desperate trying, I'd say the SDK is useless. Then I found a program which is just what I need, written by a guy named S.Bronner. But the problem is that his program is made for Python in UNIX, and I would need it to work in Windows with python. So I'm asking, is there anyone who could examine this code and convert it to work in windows for me? My Python skills are not good enough to accomplish this. Here is the code which should be converted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

DEV_CLASS      = 3
DEV_VENDOR     = 0x0922
DEV_PRODUCT    = 0x1001
DEV_NODE       = None
DEV_NAME       = 'Dymo LabelManager PnP'
FONT_FILENAME  = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf'
FONT_SIZERATIO = 7./8

import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont
import array
import fcntl
import os
import re
import struct
import subprocess
import sys
import termios
import textwrap

class DymoLabeler:
    """
    Create and work with a Dymo LabelManager PnP object.

This class contains both mid-level and high-level functions. In general,
the high-level functions should be used. However, special purpose usage
may require the mid-level functions. That is why they are provided.
However, they should be well understood before use. Look at the
high-level functions for help. Each function is marked in its docstring
with 'HLF' or 'MLF' in parentheses.
"""

def __init__(self, dev):
    """Initialize the LabelManager object. (HLF)"""
    self.maxBytesPerLine = 8  # 64 pixels on a 12mm-tape
    self.ESC = 0x1b
    self.SYN = 0x16
    self.cmd = []
    self.rsp = False
    self.bpl = None
    self.dtb = 0
    if not os.access(dev, os.R_OK | os.W_OK): return False
    self.dev = open(dev, 'r+')

def sendCommand(self):
    """Send the already built command to the LabelManager. (MLF)"""
    if len(self.cmd) == 0: return
    cmdBin = array.array('B', self.cmd)
    cmdBin.tofile(self.dev)
    self.cmd = []
    if not self.rsp: return
    self.rsp = False
    rspBin = self.dev.read(8)
    rsp = array.array('B', rspBin).tolist()
    return rsp

def resetCommand(self):
    """Remove a partially built command. (MLF)"""
    self.cmd = []
    self.rsp = False

def buildCommand(self, cmd):
    """Add the next instruction to the command. (MLF)"""
    self.cmd += cmd

def statusRequest(self):
    """Set instruction to get the device's status. (MLF)"""
    cmd = [self.ESC, ord('A')]
    self.buildCommand(cmd)
    self.rsp = True

def dotTab(self, value):
    """Set the bias text height, in bytes. (MLF)"""
    if value < 0 or value > self.maxBytesPerLine: raise ValueError
    cmd = [self.ESC, ord('B'), value]
    self.buildCommand(cmd)
    self.dtb = value
    self.bpl = None

def tapeColor(self, value):
    """Set the tape color. (MLF)"""
    if value < 0: raise ValueError
    cmd = [self.ESC, ord('C'), value]
    self.buildCommand(cmd)

def bytesPerLine(self, value):
    """Set the number of bytes sent in the following lines. (MLF)"""
    if value < 0 or value + self.dtb > self.maxBytesPerLine: raise ValueError
    if value == self.bpl: return
    cmd = [self.ESC, ord('D'), value]
    self.buildCommand(cmd)
    self.bpl = value

def cut(self):
    """Set instruction to trigger cutting of the tape. (MLF)"""
    cmd = [self.ESC, ord('E')]
    self.buildCommand(cmd)

def line(self, value):
    """Set next printed line. (MLF)"""
    self.bytesPerLine(len(value))
    cmd = [self.SYN] + value
    self.buildCommand(cmd)

def chainMark(self):
    """Set Chain Mark. (MLF)"""
    self.dotTab(0)
    self.bytesPerLine(self.maxBytesPerLine)
    self.line([0x99] * self.maxBytesPerLine)

def skipLines(self, value):
    """Set number of lines of white to print. (MLF)"""
    if value <= 0: raise ValueError
    self.bytesPerLine(0)
    cmd = [self.SYN] * value
    self.buildCommand(cmd)

def initLabel(self):
    """Set the label initialization sequence. (MLF)"""
    cmd = [0x00] * 8
    self.buildCommand(cmd)

def getStatus(self):
    """Ask for and return the device's status. (HLF)"""
    self.statusRequest()
    rsp = self.sendCommand()
    print rsp

def printLabel(self, lines, dotTab):
    """Print the label described by lines. (HLF)"""
    self.initLabel
    self.tapeColor(0)
    self.dotTab(dotTab)
    for line in lines:
        self.line(line)
    self.skipLines(56)  # advance printed matter past cutter
    self.skipLines(56)  # add symmetric margin
    self.statusRequest()
    rsp = self.sendCommand()
    print rsp

def die(message=None):
    if message: print >> sys.stderr, message
    sys.exit(1)

def pprint(par, fd=sys.stdout):
    rows, columns = struct.unpack('HH', fcntl.ioctl(sys.stderr, termios.TIOCGWINSZ, struct.pack('HH', 0, 0)))
    print >> fd, textwrap.fill(par, columns)

def getDeviceFile(classID, vendorID, productID):
    # find file containing the device's major and minor numbers
    searchdir = '/sys/bus/hid/devices'
    pattern = '^%04d:%04X:%04X.[0-9A-F]{4}$' % (classID, vendorID, productID)
    deviceCandidates = os.listdir(searchdir)
    foundpath = None
    for devname in deviceCandidates:
        if re.match(pattern, devname):
            foundpath = os.path.join(searchdir, devname)
            break
    if not foundpath: return
    searchdir = os.path.join(foundpath, 'hidraw')
    devname = os.listdir(searchdir)[0]
    foundpath = os.path.join(searchdir, devname)
    filepath = os.path.join(foundpath, 'dev')

# get the major and minor numbers
f = open(filepath, 'r')
devnums = [int(n) for n in f.readline().strip().split(':')]
f.close()
devnum = os.makedev(devnums[0], devnums[1])

# check if a symlink with the major and minor numbers is available
filepath = '/dev/char/%d:%d' % (devnums[0], devnums[1])
if os.path.exists(filepath):
    return os.path.realpath(filepath)

# check if the relevant sysfs path component matches a file name in
# /dev, that has the proper major and minor numbers
filepath = os.path.join('/dev', devname)
if os.stat(filepath).st_rdev == devnum:
    return filepath

# search for a device file with the proper major and minor numbers
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/dev'):
    for filename in filenames:
        filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        if os.stat(filepath).st_rdev == devnum:
            return filepath

def access_error(dev):
    pprint('You do not have sufficient access to the device file %s:' % dev, sys.stderr)
    subprocess.call(['ls', '-l', dev], stdout=sys.stderr)
    print >> sys.stderr
    pprint('You probably want to add a rule in /etc/udev/rules.d along the following lines:', sys.stderr)
    print >> sys.stderr, '    SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", \\'
    print >> sys.stderr, '    ACTION=="add", \\'
    print >> sys.stderr, '    DEVPATH=="/devices/pci[0-9]*/usb[0-9]*/0003:0922:1001.*/hidraw/hidraw0", \\'
    print >> sys.stderr, '    GROUP="plugdev"'
    print >> sys.stderr
    pprint('Following that, turn off your device and back on again to activate the new permissions.', sys.stderr)


# get device file name
if not DEV_NODE:
    dev = getDeviceFile(DEV_CLASS, DEV_VENDOR, DEV_PRODUCT)
else:
    dev = DEV_NODE
if not dev: die("The device '%s' could not be found on this system." % DEV_NAME)

# create dymo labeler object
lm = DymoLabeler(dev)
if not lm: die(access_error(dev))

# check for any text specified on the command line
labeltext = [arg.decode(sys.stdin.encoding) for arg in sys.argv[1:]]
if len(labeltext) == 0: die("No label text was specified.")

# create an empty label image
labelheight = lm.maxBytesPerLine * 8
lineheight = float(labelheight) / len(labeltext)
fontsize = int(round(lineheight * FONT_SIZERATIO))
font = ImageFont.truetype(FONT_FILENAME, fontsize)
labelwidth = max(font.getsize(line)[0] for line in labeltext)
labelbitmap = Image.new('1', (labelwidth, labelheight))

# write the text into the empty image
labeldraw = ImageDraw.Draw(labelbitmap)
for i, line in enumerate(labeltext):
    lineposition = int(round(i * lineheight))
    labeldraw.text((0, lineposition), line, font=font, fill=255)
del labeldraw

# convert the image to the proper matrix for the dymo labeler object
labelrotated = labelbitmap.transpose(Image.ROTATE_270)
labelstream = labelrotated.tostring()
labelstreamrowlength = labelheight/8 + (1 if labelheight%8 != 0 else 0)
if len(labelstream)/labelstreamrowlength != labelwidth: die('An internal problem was encountered while processing the label bitmap!')
labelrows = [labelstream[i:i+labelstreamrowlength] for i in range(0, len(labelstream), labelstreamrowlength)]
labelmatrix = [array.array('B', labelrow).tolist() for labelrow in labelrows]

# optimize the matrix for the dymo label printer
dottab = 0
while max(line[0] for line in labelmatrix) == 0:
    labelmatrix = [line[1:] for line in labelmatrix]
    dottab += 1
for line in labelmatrix:
    while len(line) > 0 and line[-1] == 0:
        del line[-1]

# print the label
lm.printLabel(labelmatrix, dottab)
```

Comment: SO is not a code porting service - especially for code that interacts with custom hardware. If you need a whole program written, hire someone to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
FONT_FILENAME  = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-bitstream-vera/Vera.ttf'
// should be changed to path to the font on your system
```

won't work because of filesystem differences.

```
searchdir = '/sys/bus/hid/devices'
// take a look at "pywinusb" library (?)
```

won't work either, you have to get the devices in a different way. Not sure from where though. The same problem is

```
filepath = '/dev/char/%d:%d' % (devnums[0], devnums[1])
```

this isn't accessible in Windows and you have to do in a different way.

Besides that everything else looks OS independent. If you have any errors after fixing previous 3 problems, then edit them into your question please.